# Elasticsearch Modeling Best Practices

Tags: java, elasticsearch, data-modeling, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've recently started working with Elasticsearch and is in the process of persisting some data into it via Spring Data Elasticsearch.

I'm relatively new for the NoSQL databases.

I want to know the best way to model an Audit Log for a user.

Currently I see two approaches.

The first one is to create a single document per log entry.

Something similar to this

```
@Document(indexName = "user_audit_log", type = "UserAuditLog")
public class UserAuditLog {

    @Id
    private String uuid;

    private Long userID;

    private String action;

    private String original;

    private String newValue;

    private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
}
```

And write the entries in a similar fashion to a RDBMS. The major advantage I see in this approach is that there's no need to worry about write concurrency.

Second approach is to have a single document per user. And the log entries be places in a list inside there.

Something similar to this.

```
public class UserAuditLogEntry {
    private String action;

    private String original;

    private String newValue;

    private OffsetDateTime timestamp;

}

@Document(indexName = "user_audit_log", type = "UserAuditLog")
public class UserAuditLog {

    @Id
    private Long userID;

    private List<UserAuditLogEntry> auditLogEntries;
}
```

The document has to be loaded and the `auditLogEntries` collection need to be updated and the whole model has to be persisted again.

The major drawback I can think of is the need for concurrent write protection.

Which one is the best practice in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a question for the scope of Stack Overflow (you'll probably get close requests).

Use the first one. Not only because of concurrency, but why storing these entries in a datastore when you do not want things like search for entries in a time range, or entries containing special text etc? You might do this with the second version as well, but imagine that the user after a while has 1 million log entries, and you want to find a special one. Using the second approach, a search will always return the whole object with all entries in it.

When adding a new entry you would first have to read all entries in the big object from Elasticsearch and then write them back; this will get slower and slower, not only because of the amount of data transferred, but because all already existing entries would be reindexed when the modified document is stored.

And while setting up indexing on a nested object might work, it way more complicated than when using the first solution.

So just save the single entries in Elasticsearch, there's absolutely no reason to not do it.

And if you want to use fancy dashboards like Kibana, that works straight away with this approach as well.